# Transaction rollback chaining in stored procedure

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

For example, i have 2 stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sProcedure1]
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    EXEC sProcedure2
    SELECT * INTO Table3 FROM Table2

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sProcedure2]
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    SELECT * INTO Table2 FROM Table1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

What if sProcedure2 will execute successfully but sProcedure1 will get error on SELECT * INTO Table3 FROM Table2 ?

Will Table2 be filled with data or Rollback from sProcedure1 will populate to sProcedure2 ?

Thank you

Comment: It Will Rollback The transaction and table2 will not be create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me if Stored Proc 1 fails everything should be rolled back and you wont have any data inserted in Table 2 & Table 3.

Comment: You are right, i just tried it on another example. Thank you